# How can I make a non binary tree in python?

Tags: python-3.x, tree

I have a input like this input = [["hair", "hair cut", "men's haircut"], ["hair", "hair style"], ["skin", "waxing", "arm waxing"]]. Number of nodes in each sub list might not be same (Ex: 2nd element in the given element which has only 2 nodes in it). Based on this input a tree should be formed such that,

menu =

```
{
    "root": [{
        "name": "Service Menu Mapping",
        "is_root": True,
        "is_leaf": False,
        "child": [{
                "name": "hair",
                "is_root": False,
                "is_leaf": False,
                "child": [{
                        "name": "hair cut",
                        "is_root": False,
                        "is_leaf": False,
                        "child": [{
                            "name": "men's haircut",
                            "is_root": False,
                            "is_leaf": True,
                            "child": []
                        }]
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "hair style",
                        "is_root": False,
                        "is_leaf": True,
                        "child": []
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "skin",
                "is_root": False,
                "is_leaf": False,
                "child": [{
                    "name": "waxing",
                    "is_root": False,
                    "is_leaf": False,
                    "child": [{
                        "name": "arm waxing",
                        "is_root": False,
                        "is_leaf": True,
                        "child": []
                    }]
                }]
            }
        ]
    }]
}
```

I'm starting to learn algorithms on tree structures, I have been trying with this approach,
class NonBinTree:

```
class NonBinTree:
def __init__(self, val):
    self.parent = val
    self.parent[0]['child'] = []

def add_node(self, val):
    self.parent[0]['child'].append(NonBinTree(val))

def __repr__(self):
    return f"NonBinTree({self.parent}): {self.parent[0]['child']}"
```

with this approach I can create the tree manually, but if there are n number of nodes in any subsets, this is going to be mess. Can someone help with correct algorithm or approach? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The `class` will not help much with generating that output, which essentially is a nested dictionary.

You could create the item for each input string, and key it with the path to that label. Then populate those `child` lists.

Here is how that could be coded as a function:

```
def createmenu(paths):
    # Create the nodes without linking them, keyed by their path
    dct = {
        "|".join(path[:i+1]) : {
                "name": label,
                "is_root": False,
                "is_leaf": i == len(path) - 1,
                "child": []
            }
        for path in paths  
        for i, label in enumerate(path)
    }
    # Add root node, identified with an empty-string path
    dct[""] = {
        "name": "Service Menu Mapping",
        "is_root": True,
        "is_leaf": len(paths) == 0,
        "child": []
    }

    # Populate child lists
    visited = set()
    for path in paths:
        for i, label in enumerate(path):
            pathid = "|".join(path[:i+1])
            if pathid not in visited:
                visited.add(pathid)
                dct["|".join(path[:i])]["child"].append(dct[pathid])

    # Wrapper
    return {
        "root": [dct[""]]
    }
```

Example use:

```
paths = [["hair", "hair cut", "men's haircut"],
         ["hair", "hair style"],
         ["skin", "waxing", "arm waxing"]]
menu = createmenu(paths)
```

`menu` will be:

```
{
    "root": [{
        "name": "Service Menu Mapping",
        "is_root": True,
        "is_leaf": False,
        "child": [{
            "name": "hair",
            "is_root": False,
            "is_leaf": False,
            "child": [{
                "name": "hair cut",
                "is_root": False,
                "is_leaf": False,
                "child": [{
                    "name": "men's haircut",
                    "is_root": False,
                    "is_leaf": True,
                    "child": []
                }]
            }, {
                "name": "hair style",
                "is_root": False,
                "is_leaf": True,
                "child": []
            }]
        }, {
            "name": "skin",
            "is_root": False,
            "is_leaf": False,
            "child": [{
                "name": "waxing",
                "is_root": False,
                "is_leaf": False,
                "child": [{
                    "name": "arm waxing",
                    "is_root": False,
                    "is_leaf": True,
                    "child": []
                }]
            }]
        }]
    }]
}
```

Comment: Any feedback on this answer? Did it suit your needs?

Comment: this is awesome. I have been breaking my head to solve this, You are such a genius. Can you please give me suggest my the algorithm which helped you solve this? How do these kind of logic strike your mind?

Comment: Can we solve it using DFS or BFS algorithms?